# How to organize code in CodeIgniter's templates?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, templates

I don't really know how to organize my code in a CodeIgniter project. In a view, I have a form which allows after submit to have information. But the information is display on the same view. The information is displayed in multiple ways (like with PHP or with Ajax and JSON encoding in the controller part).

My view :

```
<form action="#" method="post">
 <p>Your name : <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" value="OK"></p>
</form>
```

Can I use that in the view to verify if the used pressed the button submit ?

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {// the code I want to to show after submit}
```

What I want to display after the click on the submit button :

```
<select class="mylist">
    <?php foreach($groups as $each){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $each->groupname; ?>"><?php echo $each->groupname; ?></option>';
    <?php } ?>
</select>

  <table id="table" class="display" style="width:80%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>SurName</th>
                <th>ID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr> 
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>SurName</th>
                <th>ID</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
</table>
```

Controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view("myview.php");
}

public function getlist()
{
    $this->load->model('mymodel');
// Method to get the values of the list in the database

}
public function get_test_datatables()
{
// Method to fill the datatable part
echo json_encode($output);
}

JS Functions :

    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#table').DataTable({
    //Get the data with ajax
    })

    )}
```

After I press the submit button, I also want to check if a checkbox is checked (if it equal to true in the database, I have to check the box, if it is equal to false, I don't have to check it). Have I to do something like that in the view:

```
if(checkbox->value == true)
{
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" checked> I have a bike<br>
}
else {
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Show complete code with ajax functions and all. There is a plugin you might want to look into for CI called ignited datatables which might help you out. Otherwise the datatables docs are pretty good for this sort of thing. Try something/flesh this out a bit more, and come back. As it stands I believe you are asking us to do too much for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my projects I allways sends the data via ajax ($.post()) and divide the view in two divs: one with the list, wich is visible, and another with the form, with is invisible.
On the list part, there are a button witch switchs to the form.
When I click on submit, sends data and, if success, show success message and return to the list div.

HTML:

```
<div id="div-form" style="display: none;">
    <form>
     <p>Your name : <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
     <button type="button" id="save">OK</button>
     <button type="button" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="div-list">
    <button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
    <select class="mylist">
        <?php foreach($groups as $each): ?>
            <option value="<?= $each->groupname; ?>">
                <?= $each->groupname; ?>
            </option>';
        <?php endif; ?>
    </select>

      <table id="table" class="display" style="width:80%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>SurName</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr> 
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>SurName</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $(document).on('click', "#add", function() {
        $("#div-form").show();
        $("#div-list").hide();
    });

    $(document).on('click', "#save", function() {
        $.post('service_link', {
            name: $("#name").val()
        }, function(data) {
            $("#div-list").show();
            $("#div-form").hide();
            $('#table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
        }, 'json');
    });

    $(document).on('click', "#cancel", function() {
        $("#div-list").show();
        $("#div-form").hide();
    });

    $('#table').DataTable({
    //Get the data with ajax
    })
});
```